# Is EPOLLONESHOT guaranteed to only wake one thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, epoll

I have a pool of threads all calling `epoll_wait` on an epoll instance that is watching a set of file descriptors. All of the descriptors have been added to the epoll instance with `EPOLLONESHOT`. Is it guaranteed that only one thread will wake up when a file descriptor is triggered? Or is it possible that multiple threads will wake up? To rephrase that question, `EPOLLONESHOT` guaranteed to be thread safe and only wake one thread?

My testing seems to indicate that only one thread will wake up, but I'm looking for either a specification that asserts this or citations to kernel code.

Comment: I'd say that's exactly the idea. Only one thread gets the event and the fd gets disabled atomically.

Comment: Yeah, that's my experience and what my testing has shown, but I'm not sure if it's a *guarantee* and if anyone can cite a specification or something that would give me a lot more confidence :P